# Netlogo memory increase

Tags: netlogo

Im using Windows 7-64bit.I'm creating a model in NetLogo that needs an approx 500x500 world. So I'm going to need a lot of memory .I need to increase the memory limit .Can somebody please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By making a quick search in Google, I found this that may be what you're looking for:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#how-big-can-my-model-be-how-many-turtles-patches-procedures-buttons-and-so-on-can-my-model-contain

Comment: yup, and re: 64-bit Windows specifically, see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/423